# Python - PYQT5 print missing letter in QtextEdit

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qtextedit

```
    self.textBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.frame_2)
    #self.textBrowser.setFontFamily("Courier")
    self.textBrowser.setFontFamily("Consolas")
    self.textBrowser.setFontPointSize(10)
    self.textBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 1041, 301))
    self.textBrowser.setStyleSheet("background-color:rgb(255, 255, 255)")
    self.textBrowser.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.WinPanel)
    self.textBrowser.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
    self.textBrowser.setLineWidth(0)
    self.textBrowser.setObjectName("textBrowser")
    self.textBrowser.document().setMaximumBlockCount(900)
    self.textBrowser.setReadOnly(True)
    self.textBrowser.insertPlainText(text + "\n")
```

for ex i have text like  "path 1 . 203A"
it prints on GUI like this " ath 1    A"

but when i copy from Text Edit Box to Notepad I don't get missing character, anyone know why it has this issue  on QtextEdit ? i tried changing fonts  which was related to Courier but the same issue still exist.

Comment: Have you found a solution? I have the same problem with the letter 'L', and intermittently (sometimes it's with 'E' and 'L'), but in my case it either prints a blank space or a garbage block-like character.